# android java lang abstractstringbuilder enlargebuffer out of memory error

Tags: java, android

In my application i try to implement cache data in my device to present it in offline mode. it works fine before but now i get this crash.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:132)
   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:124)
   at org.json.JSONStringer.string(JSONStringer.java:344)
   at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:252)
   at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:672)
   at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:237)
   at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:672)
   at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:237)
   at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:672)
   at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:237)
   at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:672)
   at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:237)
   at org.json.JSONArray.writeTo(JSONArray.java:602)
   at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:233)
   at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:672)
   at org.json.JSONObject.toString(JSONObject.java:641)
```

and this is line where the issue happen 
            `mCaching.cache(response.toString(), Caching.TYPE_GLOBAL);`

 the issue happen to try to convert my `JsonObject` to String in this code `response.toString()`

after search for the problem some answers suggest to add `android:largeHeap="true"` in my application manifest file but i already add it before the crash produced. any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the object you're trying to write as JSON has a circular reference loop. It's quite difficult to actually run out of memory unless you're loading a lot of huge images, but with text content, not so much, unless the data you're saving is huge, which I doubt.

Regardless in this case you should consider writing the JSON directly to a file instead of a memory String. Also, it's best to write to a temporary file first, then move that file to replace the previously saved data, to save you in case the writing fails mid-operation.

Comment: so, should i delete this object from cache Dir then write it again ?

Comment: First write a temporary file to cache dir, then rename it with the actual name (e.g. cache_temp.json -> cache.json), when you load data check for cache.json, it has the latest successfully saved data.

Comment: Remember to also check that you don't have a reference loop in the saved data!

Comment: How to check this ?

Comment: Go through the data you're about to save with the debugger, open the object tree and see if a child object refers to one of its ancestors.